# How to parallelize a double loop with MPI with reading files in the inner loop?

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have parallelized parallelize this piece of code below with MPI for the first loop `jh` and with OpenMP for the 3rd triple loop (`iz`,`ix`,`iy`).

My problem is that this triple loop takes about 25s and the 2nd loop can go up to 100000 which makes it quite long.

Is there a possibility to parallelize the 2nd loop `is` with MPI as well?

```
do jh=rank+1,nh,size

   ! Initializing O 
   O=0.

   do is=1,ns

      ! Reading file1
      call readfile(file1(is),I)

      ! Reading file2
      call readfile(file2(is),H)

      !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(iz,ix,iy,ih) COLLAPSE(3)
      do iz=1,nz
         do ix=1,nx
            do iy=1,ny

               ih=H(iz,ix,iy)

               if (ih.eq.jh) then
                  O(iz,ix,iy)=O(iz,ix,iy)+I(iz,ix,iy)
               endif

            enddo ! iy
         enddo ! ix
      enddo ! iz
      !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

   enddo ! isrc

   call writefile(out,O)

   ! Initializing for the next offset
   O=0.
   no=1

enddo ! jh
```

Comment: In principle yes, as written all all iterations of the is loop are independent, therefore it can be parallelised. In practice it will depend on how well your filesystem and associated software can cope with multiple accesses at one time

Comment: You typically do not use MPI to parallelize *a loop*. You use MPI to parallelize the entire program. does your program already use MPI in any way? MPI is all about distributing the data on which the separate processes work. Not just about loops like in OpenMP. Do not bring in MPI to just parallelize some reading. Use MPI if you want the whole program to be parallel in a distributed way.

Comment: The first loop `do jh=rank+1,nh,size` is  MPI parallelized.

Comment: Not sure about OpenMP or MPI for speeding up the loops.  But, you're accessing `O(iz,ix,iy)` and `I(iz,ix,iy)` in the wrong order.  If `nz`, `nx`, and `ny` are larger than a 100 or more, then you're blowing out your memory cache.

Comment: @evets, oups! you're right. I missed that. Thanks.